# Xpath combine two treepaths

Tags: python, xpath

I have two calls:

```
teamName = tree.xpath('//span[@class="name matchwinner"]/text()')
teamMatch = tree.xpath('//a[@class="match"]/@href')
```

At the moment i get two arrays, one with team names and one with hrefs. Is there a way to get something like [team1, href1, team2, href2]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect each team names and team matches share the same parent. If this is the case, you can do something like:

```
for team in tree.xpath("//div[@class='game']"):
    teamName = team.xpath('.//span[@class="name matchwinner"]/text()')[0]
    teamMatch = team.xpath('.//a[@class="match"]/@href')[0]

    print(teamName, teamMatch)
```

Or, you can also use `zip()` to group names and matches together by index:

```
teamName = tree.xpath('//span[@class="name matchwinner"]/text()')
teamMatch = tree.xpath('//a[@class="match"]/@href')

print(list(zip(teamName, teamMatch)))
```

Comment: [Here](http://i.imgur.com/nLFzuOs.png) is a overview over the structure. I'm only looking if Wings won a game. At the moment i'm getting wrong matchlinks. Site is dailydota2.com. The zip print looks like something i want but it adds the wrong pairs

Comment: @user273032 okay, updated the first option - does it work for you?

Comment: Gives me a "list index out of range" error from the teamNames. I checked the match links and it appears that the href tree gets live and upcoming matches aswell, i think i need to limit it to the <div id="past games" class="box past"</div>

Comment: Ok i'm using it like this now: for team in tree.xpath("//div[@class='box past']") and i think its fine now since this excludes any other matches than the recent ones so there is no desync in the arrays. Thank you very much you helped me alot getting a better understanding of this!